# How to edit publication's generation_leveling_threshold configuration value

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, replication, merge-replication

I dont know where I put this code:

update sysmergepublications set [generation_leveling_threshold] = 0

I only need do it. But I need edited any funcion of agent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you may be looking for is [`sp_changemergepublication`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186905.aspx).

This stored procedure will allow you to modify **generation_leveling_threshold** value.